# Como funciona este loop para verificar duplicatas?

Tags: javascript, array

O código abaixo cria um outro array filtrando para não existir valores duplicados:

```js
var array = [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5];
var models = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
   if ( array.indexOf( array[ i ] ) === i ) {
      models.push(array[ i ] );
   }
}
console.log(models);
```

Resultado:

`models = [1,2,3,4,5]`

Porém não consegui entender como ele faz isso no trecho:

```
array.indexOf( array[ i ] ) === i )
```

Como ele verifica se é duplicado através desse trecho?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), `indexOf` retorna o primeiro índice que possui o elemento informado. Ex:

```js
let array = [ 1, 2, 3, 1, 4];

console.log(array.indexOf(1)); // 0
```

O número 1 está em duas posições do array (nas posições zero e 3 - lembre-se que a primeira posição é zero, a segunda é 1, etc), mas `array.indexOf(1)` retorna `0`, pois é o índice correspondente à primeira ocorrência de `1` dentro do array.

Então `array.indexOf( array[ i ] )` verifica a primeira posição em que ocorre o elemento `array[i]` (ou seja, qual a primeira posição em que ocorre o elemento da posição `i`). Se essa posição for diferente de `i`, significa que o elemento está duplicado.

Usando o nosso array acima como exemplo: quando `i` for igual a `3`, `array[i]` será o número 1 (a segunda ocorrência do número 1). Só que `array.indexOf( array[ i ] )`, como já vimos, retorna zero, que é diferente de `3`, e portanto aí eu detectei que o elemento é repetido.

Então na verdade o `if` detecta a primeira ocorrência de cada elemento. Caso seja diferente, não entra no `if`, pois aí eu sei que é duplicado e não preciso inserir o elemento novamente em `models`.

---

A partir do ES6, você pode usar um [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) para obter o mesmo resultado:

```js
let array = [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5];

let models = Array.from(new Set(array));
console.log(models); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// ou usando spread syntax: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
models = [... new Set(array)];
console.log(models); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

Por fim, vale lembrar que `indexOf` sempre [verifica o array desde o primeiro elemento](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.indexof), ou seja, para cada elemento do array, estarei percorrendo o mesmo array várias vezes, desde o início até a primeira ocorrência do elemento (um variação do [*Shlemiel the painter’s algorithm*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/)).

Por isso esse algoritmo pode se tornar bem ineficiente conforme o array aumenta (para arrays pequenos não vai fazer tanta diferença, mas para arrays maiores, pode ser um problema, principalmente se não tiver muitos elementos repetidos).

Uma outra abordagem seria ter um objeto para guardar os elementos que já foram encontrados:

```js
let array = [1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5];
let models = [];
let encontrados = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // só adiciono quem ainda não foi encontrado
    if (encontrados[array[i]] === undefined){
       encontrados[array[i]] = true;
       models.push(array[i]);
    }
}
console.log(models);
```

Fazendo um teste básico com um array com mais de 10 mil elementos, [esta abordagem se mostrou bem mais rápida que as outras](https://jsbench.me/04k7ys87ck/2). Mas para um array pequeno, [`indexOf` foi mais rápido](https://jsbench.me/n2k7yslq9f/1).